# Ruby On Rails 3.2.3 - Displaying Information From Two Models On The Same View

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to display a country name on a view.  I have a User model with country_id that belongs_to :countries.  I have a Country model with id, iso & name that has many :users.

This is what I have in the controller for the Show view: @user = User.find(params[:id])

I thought that with this relationship setup I could do user.country.name or user.countries.name and get the country name.  However I get the following error, both in the view or in the user controller.  It does not matter if I have user, country or countries capitalized or not.

Failure/Error: click_button "Save changes"
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined local variable or method `user' for #<#:0x007fb9548a7ae0>

I thought I would try this in the view: Country.find(@user.country_id).name

This works as expected in the Rails console.  It is showing the correct country id value that I want the name for.  As I stated when I do this command in the Rails console I get the correct value.  In the console I first assigned @user as I do in the controller.  Afterwards I do the Country.find command.  However in the view I get the following error on the Country.find command:

Failure/Error: click_button "Save changes"
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       Couldn't find Country with id=1

When I display the value it looks like this:

```
#<Country:0x007ffd6bf9ac20>
```

I get the same error when I created an instance variable @country_name set to the Country.find command.  I'm lost because the United States record has id = 1 in Country and I can find it in the Rails console.

I have checked the web, including Stack Overflow.  A similar question about showing information from two models has been asked a good number of times here.  They have not been answered except for the two options I tried but cannot get to work.  Once I can get this working I will probably create a user helper for this.

Comment: If your User model has a country_id, it `belongs_to :country` not `belongs_to :countries`. It would be easier to help if you could post the code for your Country and User models.

Comment: I did some more checking. I ended up restarting AGAIN the rails server, guard & spork. I was finally able to get the country name working with setting @country_name = Country.find(@user.country_id).name.  Now I need to redo my Rspec2 tests to include this logic somehow using FactoryGirl.